# Installing DBLink for Postgres 9

Tags: sql, linux, dblink, postgresql

Can someone please shed some light on how to install the requirements for Postgres 9 (Centos) to be able to use dblink for inter-postgres db querying.

There seems to be no clean documentation out there on how to install dblink requirements in general.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install DbLink
DbLink is located in share/contribs/dblink.sql of your PostgreSQL install.To use it, load the dblink.sql file in the database you would like to use it in.

Source: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

Answer (score 38):

If you have PostgreSQL 9.1 (or later), make sure the contrib package is installed, e.g., from your shell:

```
yum install postgres*contrib
```

Then within the database, use the DDL to create the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

Comment: on my system, you need to add another asterisk, in case the system is: `sudo yum install postgresql92-contrib.x86_64` I would have done `sudo yum install postgresql*contrib*`

Comment: I had to do sudo apt-get install postgres*contrib.